How do we understand the wish “עד ביאת הגואל" given to someone observing a Yahrzeit?
Jews from Ashkenaz (Yekkes) tend to wish “עד ביאת הגואל" (= until the coming of the Redeemer)  on the occasion of a Yahrzeit.
How should we understand this wish?
Does it mean:
1] You should live and continue to observe the Yahrzeit until Moshiach comes or ..
2] You should meet your departed relative when  Moshiach comes or ..
3] is there another meaning?
[1] seems to imply that Moshiach will be a long time coming.
related: Why do we wish someone “long life” on the occasion of the anniversary of the death of relative?
What to say to someone on a yahrzeit
